# Feynman diagram for the 2-point one-loop 1PI diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

If I have the $\phi^3$-interactive theory. How can I draw the Feynman diagram for the 2-point one-loop 1PI diagram?

Comment: What have you tried? This shouldn't be very hard

Comment: Yes, it was a previous homework. We have the solution but I don’t understand why he drawn that graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down each term:

- $\phi^3$ means that each interaction vertex has three lines attached to it
- 2-point means the diagram has two external lines
- 1-loop means that any other lines need to be contracted to form a single loop

Now for these conditions, as you can verify, there are two possible diagrams [source: physicspages.com, *Lancaster*]:

[image: Feynman Diagrams]

But the final condition, being 1PI, means that it should not be possible to cut an internal line such that the diagram separates into two parts. That eliminates diagram (b), leaving diagram (a) as the 1PI, 2-point, 1-loop diagram for $\phi^3$ theory.

Comment: Thank you. I just didn’t understand if i have only one cubic vertex and one propagator how can I connect them to get those diagrams. If I do the second order perturbation I have 2 cubic vertices and 2 propagators get those diagrams right?

Comment: Correct, the 2-point loop diagrams start appearing at second order since they require at least 2 vertices.